# haskell acceptFork for http server

Tags: haskell, tcplistener

I have to create a http server in haskell. For this I have to define an acceptFork function which handles the incoming TCP connections, which has the following type:

```
acceptFork :: Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
```

The way how this should work is the following:

- use the accept function to accept an incoming connection, which returns a Handle
- disable buffering with hSetBuffering function (set value to NoBuffering)
- set new line char with hSetNewlineMode function (use parameter (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF))
- start a new thread which runs the input action on the handle value
- recurisvely wait for the next connection

What I've came up with so far is this:

```
import qualified Network.Socket as NS

acceptFork :: Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
acceptFork lsock k = do
    (csock,_) <- NS.accept lsock
    hSetBuffering lsock NoBuffering
    hSetNewlineMode lsock (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF)
    forkIO (k csock)
```

The problem is that it doesn't even compile. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

This is the error that I get:

```
bead2.hs:31:23:
Couldn't match expected type `(Handle -> BufferMode -> IO ())
                              -> Socket
                              -> BufferMode
                              -> (Handle -> NewlineMode -> IO ())
                              -> Socket
                              -> NewlineMode
                              -> IO (Handle, t0)'
            with actual type `IO (Socket, NS.SockAddr)'
The function `NS.accept' is applied to 7 arguments,
but its type `Socket -> IO (Socket, NS.SockAddr)' has only one
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  conn@(csock, _) <- NS.accept
                       lsock
                       hSetBuffering
                       lsock
                       NoBuffering
                       hSetNewlineMode
                       lsock
                       (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF)
In the expression:
  do { conn@(csock, _) <- NS.accept
                            lsock
                            hSetBuffering
                            lsock
                            NoBuffering
                            hSetNewlineMode
                            lsock
                            (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF);
       forkIO (k csock) }

bead2.hs:34:5:
Couldn't match type `ThreadId' with `()'
Expected type: IO ()
  Actual type: IO ThreadId
In a stmt of a 'do' block: forkIO (k csock)
In the expression:
  do { conn@(csock, _) <- NS.accept
                            lsock
                            hSetBuffering
                            lsock
                            NoBuffering
                            hSetNewlineMode
                            lsock
                            (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF);
       forkIO (k csock) }
```

Comment: first please add the error-message you get - thanks

Comment: **btw**: most of the first stuff is from the *indentation*  problem I thought was introduced with your copy&pasting the code into Stack-Overflow - but it seems you really intended it all to the level of `acceptFork` (and I wrongly edited out ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I copied what you have and added the missing parts (for network > 2.6 and < 2.7):

```
import qualified Network.Socket as NS
import System.IO (Handle, hSetBuffering, hSetNewlineMode, BufferMode(..), Newline(..), NewlineMode(..), IOMode(..))
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO, ThreadId)

acceptFork :: NS.Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ThreadId
acceptFork lsock k = do
    (csock,_) <- NS.accept lsock
    hsock <- NS.socketToHandle csock ReadWriteMode
    hSetBuffering hsock NoBuffering
    hSetNewlineMode hsock (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF)
    forkIO (k hsock)
```

basically you have:

- lot's of missing imports
- need to get the handle from the socket via `NS.socketToHandle`
- watch out for the result of `forkIO` (the new thread's id)

this compiles under:

```
 base >=4.8 && <4.9, network >=2.6 && <2.7
```

#### disclaimer

I did **not** run this code so I have no clue if it works - but it will compile (on my system ;) )

#### without `ThreadId`:

just change the signature and last lines:

```
acceptFork :: NS.Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
acceptFork lsock k = do
    -- ... same as above
    _ <- forkIO (k hsock)
    return ()
```

#### fork and wait for the next connection:

just call `acceptFork` recursively

```
acceptFork :: NS.Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
acceptFork lsock k = do
    (csock,_) <- NS.accept lsock
    hsock <- NS.socketToHandle csock ReadWriteMode
    hSetBuffering hsock NoBuffering
    hSetNewlineMode hsock (NewlineMode CRLF CRLF)
    _ <- forkIO (k hsock)
    acceptFork lsock k
```

or use [`forever`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forever)

```
...
import Control.Monad (forever)

acceptFork :: NS.Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
acceptFork lsock k = ...

acceptAll :: NS.Socket -> (Handle -> IO ()) -> IO ()
acceptAll sock = forever . acceptFork sock
```

Comment: Thank you. And two more questions: 1. What should I do with the thread's id? Do I even need it? 2. Where should I call this function recursively to be able to handle the next client?

Comment: BTW, now I get only one error:  `Couldn't match type `ThreadId' with `()'
Expected type: IO ()
  Actual type: IO ThreadId`

Comment: if you don't need the id just ignore it - and on how you should call it? Well maybe you might want to call it recursively to wait for the next caller - but this will depend on your problem

Comment: you get the new error either because you did not change the signature of `acceptFork` or where you are using it - I will edit out the `ThreadId`

Comment: btw: why write your own HTTP server anyway? There are plenty out there (look for [Scotty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) if you need a very lightweigth one) - I understand it if you want to experiment but if you want results quickly better look for a framework